# Long lifespans and risk aversion

Tags: society, futurology, medicine, far-future

Suppose in all types of medicine will be sufficiently advanced to enable very long life spans (many thousands of years +). I imagine that a cure for pretty much all diseases, disorders and morbidities would be developed (including those to combat aging). Nevertheless, these people will still be vulnerable to other risks (car crashes, being murdered, falling in the shower and so on). What would these people's attitudes towards these risks be?

One hypothesis is that since there is so much to lose, these people will be so risk averse that it will cripple what we consider to be normal life. Few will want to risk a very long life so few will want to cross the street, take up dangerous professions, or even drive or travel through space.

One counterpoint to consider is that if this hypothesis were true (that those with more life-years to lose are more risk averse) we would expect fewer young people than older people would be risk-taking. But obviously more younger people bungee jump, skydive and do generally riskier things than older people.

Perhaps the life-years risked by young people today are just too few for this risk aversion effect to really arise, but given a sufficiently great life-extension, it is plausible that having many years ahead will make people very risk averse.

---

This has been put off-topic as opinion-based, but as an economist, I know that risk attitudes can be rigorously studied. Obviously my question is highly speculative (as are most questions on Worldbuilding) but I don't consider it necessarily opinion-based.

A comment suggested that humans might be irrationally risk-taking because (perhaps due to cognitive biases and other cognitive limitations) we fail take into account the far future. Moreover, it's quite common for people to fail to internalize 'tail-risk' (i.e. low probability events). However, I expect that this sufficiently advanced society could cognitively enhance themselves, and improve this ability. (To some extent this is already happening, with the development of useful concepts about rationality and risk).

Comment: Purely my opinion, which is a problem with this question, that's all anyone can give you, but I don't think humans can actually think in the timescales involved so you wouldn't see any appreciable change in behaviour.

Comment: Are they all cyborg clones? If not, everyone will have a different attitude depending on relgion, cultural background, personal philosophy, experiences in life ... Asking about how much % of them will be bungee jumping (which was a short fad over a decade ago, I guess less with every year) is simply unpredictable. This is one of those questions that cannot be answered because who could possible know that? That means in your story, you can do whatever you like with it - nobody can ever prove you wrong

Comment: I agree with Ash. Evidence generally is that risk taking is part of life, especially within the young. Considering that what would be considered 'young' may actually change as a consequence, risk taking in later life may actually increase, particularly when advances in medicine make the consequences of mishap, short of death, more likely to be temporary (especially given a possible lifespan of thousands of years).

Comment: You may be interested in [What are the disadvantages of a long living race?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/53189/29) which deals with similar time scales as your question does (average life span 5,000 years). Fair enough disclosure: One of the higher voted answers is my own.

Comment: Is there evidence that humans today (life expectancy > 60yr, maximum span > 100yr) are on average more risk-averse than the ancient Greeks? This should provide at least a factual ground for the statements in the question.

Comment: Shifting on the paradox, all deaths are caused by being alive. Remove that and there will be no risks!

Comment: I think that this is a legit question which can be answered within the limits of available psychological knowledge. Unfortunately, I cannot vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Olga You can, however, make your argument in [chat] or on [meta]. A fair number of high-reputation users hang out in both places. Particularly if you post on Meta (using the specific-question tag), do add a link to that question here so that more people will see it.

Comment: @NofP the Greeks at least **claimed** to be risk-seeking.  E.g., Achilles' choice: 'My mother Thetis tells me that there are two ways in which I may meet my end. If I stay here and fight, I shall not return alive but my name will live for ever: whereas if I go home my name will die, but it will be long ere death shall take me.'  The audience was all in the glory camp...

Comment: I'm recommending the question be reopened, as there is enough data -- anecdotal, sociological, sci fi-ical, and above all **from the Iliad** -- that people could make a reasonable run on the question.

Comment: Hi all, nominating for re-opening again. The argument made by the author that risk is quantifiable is accurate, just search google scholar for [many](https://www.princeton.edu/~yacine/risk.pdf) [articles](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f2b3/91ab22787892dc36ef62ce6c3bb6552e5938.pdf) on the matter. See debate [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5536/23519), but for the people who would vote to close: just because _you_ think that a subject is opinion based, doesn't mean someone else doesn't have the expertise to answer it.

Comment: I regret that I can't agree to reopen.  All risk analysis that we know of is based on the average lifespan and human reaction to that lifespan over the course of at least hundreds of years of cultural development.  There's no basis for people who live M+ years.  With the exception of the obvious murder/war rate due to exponential overpopulation, why would any adult up to 950 years in age think any more of their risks than would a normal 35 year old?  The answer to that question is 100% opinion based.

Comment: To continue, if the question were changed to "what cultural and social changes might happen if our lifespans were elongated to M+ years?" then we can create answers (e.g., the war/murder issue mentioned above) that can be extrapolated from applicable history and science.  With that data, an actuary could estimate human reaction to those risks.

Answer (score 2):

Do young people tend to engage in risky behavior because they're young, or just because their bodies are more adapted to it? In this case if you have anti-ageing treatments, it could be that the rate of participation in risky activities actually increases.

Consider that for most people, parachuting is a "bucket list" item, something they want to do *eventually*, when they have time and money.

But as we know, young people have time and health but no money, middle aged people have money and health but no time, and old people have time and money but no longer the necessary vitality. If the last part is no longer true (because people have essentially centuries to accumulate money and vacation time without their health deteriorating), it's likely everyone will eventually try parachuting, or white water rafting, or whatever kind of high-risk activity that people usually put to later.

It's easy to maintain this "one day.." mentality and end up missing a 10 year window where you could realistically have pulled it off. It's harder when the window is 200 or 500 years. If anything, eventually you would be bored of everything else.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that even with extremely long lifetimes, young people will still be less risk averse.
Understanding the reasons why is fairly simple.
First, being risk averse is a matter of good judgement.
Judgement is partially a result of integrating experience.
So making mistakes (that you survive) becomes part of the basis for later having more sound judgement.
Secondly, the perceptual basis is different. A teenager will complain that waiting a year for something, say a drivers license "is forever".
A year to a fifteen year old represents 6and 2/3 percent of their life.
A fifty year old for whom that same period is 2 percent of their lifetime, is more likely to say, "ok I'll wait another year for whatever it is."

I think comparing the statistics for the number of overweight people today, with the insurance company actuarial data for death related to heart disease and diabetes should provide enough insight into human nature to see that medical advances won't change behavior that much.